# creating jar file for application which in turn contains external jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

Hie all  ,

I want to create an jar file for a java application, and i am able create the jar file for it properly.i followed the below link to create the jar file .[enter link description here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBzEHKXly0k)

But the problem what i am facing is that in my application i added the external jar's  like jna.jar , platform.jar and vlcj-1.2.0-javadoc.jar files to run my application successful. This application will run fine when i run in eclipse , but when i create the far file for the same application I'm getting the error like
No class defination found error.
jna native library missing.

so please will you tell me what is the actual problem and how do I solve it . and one more thing while creating the jar file I enabled the option "Export java source files and resources".

thanks in advance 
Datta

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i combine many jar files in one jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089565/can-i-combine-many-jar-files-in-one-jar-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to supply full class path when you are running your application, i.e. something like:

`java -cp myapp.jar;jna.jar;platform.jar com.mycompany.MyMain`

If you are using -jar option you should put all third party libraries to manifest.mf packaged into your jar under META-INF, i.e. add line like:

`Class-Path: jna.jar platform.jar`

to you manifest.

Pay attenition that you should use ; for windows command line, : for unix command line and space when writing class path in manifest.

Comment: Hie AlexR , can you please tell me how to create a manifest.mf file ...??? please

Comment: Hie AlexR, I found it. I just need to open jar file and place the rest of the external jars in the manifest.mf file. thanks alot

Comment: @Datta, you do not have to open jar file. You have to include manifest into your jar file when creating. Please refer to online help of `jar` utility that is a part of you jdk. If you are using ant take a look in similar jar task.