# Combining jars from multiple modules in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android project with a java library module (apply plugin: 'java' in the build.gradle file) that generates a jar on build. Another module in the project is an android plugin library (apply plugin: 'com.android.library' in the build.gradle file) and this generates a .aar file on build. The android library plugin module references the java plugin module however when building none of the .class files in the java module are added to the classes.jar of the android library module. Is there a way to combine the two into one .jar file using Gradle?

Comment: Strongly discouraged! and Duplicate?[android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700581/android-studio-how-to-package-single-aar-from-multiple-library-projects)   and Jon Skeet's answer [can-i-combine-many-jar-files-in-one-jar-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089565/can-i-combine-many-jar-files-in-one-jar-file)