# Add library into jar of project

Tags: java

My problem is with a project where I use the POI library. It's from apache and allows you to work with excel,word, ... .
I had to add some jar files to my library and it runs perfect.
The problem is when I put my JAR file somewhere else.
It gives me the errors it can't find the librarys.
Is there a way I can put my librarys into the 1 jar?

I already tried to add my lib folder as source package but that didn't help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use Maven / Gradle to manage your dependencies...

Comment: Here is one answer I [Combining Jar files into One](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5089606/6581509)

Answer (score 0):

there is a Maven plugin for Eclipse called M2Eclipse, which will read a POM and construct a classpath out of jars it finds in the local repository and any remote repositories you've configured. It behaves largely like Maven does in terms of finding the latest version for a given jar (if you've specified a version range in your POM).

You can also have a look on this
http://fredpuls.com/site/softwaredevelopment/java/deploy/five_strategies_for_managing_j.htm

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans builds your application into the project's `dist` folder. There is also a readme file in it, that tells you, you should distribute the contents of that folder...

### Edit

Remove the `lib` folder, that is shown on the second image, from your sources.

Comment: Well I use netbeans and there is no read me in it. And I don't want to sent the whole folder to someone I just want to send them the jar.

Comment: If the type of the project is application, there is a `dist/README.TXT` after building, witch contains the following line: 
To distribute this project, zip up the dist folder (including the lib folder)
and distribute the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a 'shaded' or 'uber' jar, which has all of its dependencies included

There is a maven plugin for building a shaded jar.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

For me the fastest/ easiest solution was to just open my project in eclips and export is a runable JAR then it adds the librarys to the JAR.