# Is it possible to embed (combine) an external jar file to my library project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, java

I am developing an Android project in eclipse. I am creating a `library project` that is used by a `main project`. `Main project` uses an `external jar` file. I want to add this `external jar` file to my `library project` and just add the jar file of `library project` to the `main project`. I have added that jar file in library project but when I compile library project its size is not changed and the external jar file is not embedded in the library project.

I mean I want to combine the library and the external jar into one library that my project can link to.

How can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

Comment: @iccthedral No I know this. I want to Embed it in my own library project

Comment: Are you looking for something like that: http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/source/browse/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/2.6.3/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.3.pom?r=945 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to combine the library and the external jar into one library that your project can link to? That is not possible. You cannot just combine/link two binaries (JARs) and expect them to work as one single library. Your libraries are dynamically linked and not statically, and each library is loaded in a different address space. If you want them to be as one, you need to have the source of the two libraries (your existing library and external jar) and **compile** them into one (that is, static linking).

**Update:**

Thanks Sergiu for the insight, that is quite true. The above answer was based on the precinct that a library is a binary loaded by the JRE at runtime at some memory location, and that it is formatted binary with functions/variables loaded at locations calculated by the environment - A General CS theory.

Based on your comments, I googled how to combine two JARs, and your method seems right.

Here's another SO answer: [Combine two JARs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080220/how-to-combine-two-jar-files)

Check out the 2nd answer, it also clarifies about the Manifest.mf file.

Comment: That is not quite true. Jar files are just `.zip` files with a different extensions, and in most cases it's enough to just unzip two jars in the same directory and re-zip it to "combine" jars. Also, there's no _linking_ in Java.

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu What should we do with file `MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu Thanks. I tested it and it worked. Is there any way in eclipse to do this without unzipping and zipping? Can eclipse do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can add external jars into your project using two ways:

1. right click on project, Go to `Properties`.
2. In `Java Build Path` tab select `Library` tab and click on the `Add External JARs..` button to add the external jar files into your project.
3. Click on `OK`.

The other way is to copy `jar` file into your projects `libs` folder and then right click on the `jar` file and select `Build Path>Add to Build Path.`

Try out this ways , i hope it might help you.

Comment: I have done this. But when I compile my library, I notice that it is not embedded in my jar file

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, It is defined as the **Scope** of your library. Usually the scope is  "**Provided**" which means that the library should be included in the classpath (for javac) and **not** in the **Jar** file, But in this case you should change your library scope to "**Compile**" so it also gets into the Jar file.

I don't use Eclipse so I don't know which menu to look at, But it is common property, (In Apache Maven, IntelliJ, ...) So I'm pretty sure you can find it's place on Eclipse with a little search

Long story short, **Change your Library Scope to "Compile"**