# combining jar files for BlueJ

Tags: java, jar

I have 3 jar files:

```
derby.jar 
commons.io.2.6.jar
org.json.jar
```

I tried to combine them using jarsplice-04.0jar but the fat jar doesn't work.  The only error message is the db is being accessed concurrently which just indicates the jar isn't working. I read the documentation for jarjar.jar but don't understand how to use it.  Can someone provide some guidance or a step by step procedure for combining jars (including what you need to do with the manifest.mf files)?

This stackoverflow post [How to combine two Jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080220/how-to-combine-two-jar-files) doesn't answer the question as it doesn't tell you how to combine the manifest.mf files which you apparently need to do.

Comment: Don't.  Just don't.