# How to execute a groovy script using the classes from an external jar file

Tags: java, groovy

Editing the original question.

I am trying to execute a groovy script which uses classes from an external jar. How can I execute the groovy file from command line?

This is the command I tried

```
  groovy -cp .:cicdutilities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:http-builder-0.4.0.jar Test_Execution.groovy
```

and getting the error :

```
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: /Users/sroy107/git/CICD-2020/src/main/java/com/groovy/Test_Execution.groovy: 188: unable to resolve class HTTPBuilder @ line 188, column 24. def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl) ^ 1 error`
```

I was not aware earlier that we need two jars.
This command is not working. Could somme one please help me on this.

Comment: what is the platform?  classpath uses  platform aware  aware - ";" may be ending the command.   It helps if you can add details about "not working " part.

Comment: I am trying to do this on macos..

Comment: I am getting this error:  groovy sroy107$ groovy -cp .;cicdutilities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Test_Execution.groovy
error: neither -e or filename provided

Comment: as i know on mac paths separated with colon `:`

Comment: I am not if adding : resolves my issue one step ahead but this what is happening now: I am executing the below command  groovy -cp .:cicdutilities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:http-builder-0.4.0.jar Test_Execution.groovy  and getting the error :        
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/Users/sroy107/git/CICD-2020/src/main/java/com/groovy/Test_Execution.groovy: 188: unable to resolve class HTTPBuilder
 @ line 188, column 24.
               def http = new HTTPBuilder(baseUrl)
                          ^

1 error

Comment: @SourabhRoy : please edit your question with all new details.

Comment: offtopic: Once you fix the current issue, consider using gradle/maven

Comment: edited the original question. I am trying to build a docker image thats why I wanted to execute from command line rather than maven

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue but in a very ugly way: groovy -cp .:cicdutilities-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:http-builder-0.7.1.jar:httpclient-4.3.3.jar:httpcore-4.4.13.jar:json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar:xml-resolver-1.2.jar:commons-collections-3.2.1-1.0.0.jar src/main/java/com/comcast/groovy/Test_Execution.groovy.. I wish i just could have all these jars in one jar

Comment: a jar is a zip file with some metadata in META-INF/MANIFET.MF, you can create a single jar merging all the class files in single a jar and editing a MANIFEST by hand or ignoring it, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080220/how-to-combine-two-jar-files) for a hint on how to do it